# Scala for loop multiple counters

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, and I'm trying to convert this for loop from Java:

```
for(int x=1, y=2; x<=5; x++, y+=2)
    System.out.println(x+y);
```

I'm trying to zip the values in Scala since I can't find a way to have multiple counters which are non-nested:

```
val a = Seq(1 to 5)
val b = Seq(2 to 10 by 2)
for((x,y) <- a.zip(b))
  println(x+y)
```

But the above code is giving this error:

type mismatch; found: scala.collection.immutable.Range required: String

Does anyone know how to fix this? I would prefer to do with for loop only, not while loop.

Comment: I don't know scala, but if you are doing it like this you could directly go for the result with `Seq(3 to 15 by 3)` instead of having two variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, no need to wrap the `Range` in a `Seq`:

```
val a = 1 to 5
val b = 2 to 10 by 2
for(
  (x,y) <- a.zip(b)
) 
println(x+y)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try . . .

```
((1 to 5) zip (2 to 10 by 2)).foreach(x => println(x._1+x._2))
```

Because Scala `for` comprehensions are sufficiently different from `for()` loops in other languages, it's often a good idea for beginners to avoid them until they've gained a sufficient knowledge of `map`, `flatMap`, and `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you want `x` to range from `1` to `5` and `y` is always `2*x`.  Using [for loops](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/for-loops.html) is easy for those coming from Java:

```scala
for(x <- 1 to 5; y = x*2) {
  println(s"x = $x, y = $y, x+y = ${x+y}")
}
```

---

Here is solution to a more generic problem - **iterating over elements in a collection using [multiple counters](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-for-loops-multiple-counters-multi-dimensional-arrays/) (=indices or pointers)**, like if you want to compare each 2 pairs:

```scala
val c = List("a", "b", "c", "d") //or any collection 
val end = c.length - 1 
for(i <- 0 to end-1; j <- i+1 to end)
  //compare or operate with each pair
  println(c(i)+c(j))
```

... prints:

```
ab
ac
ad
bc
bd
cd
```